# How to install a package with the new Miktex console

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, matlab

I am trying to install the mcode package to add MATLAB code in my LaTeX documents but with the new console, I do not know how do install it. The pop up window that is supposed to show when a package is not found, is not showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Which version do you talk about? Please edit your question and provide some more details for us. Including a screenshot may be useful here, as well. Thanks

Comment: I don't have an mcode package in miktex and I don't think that it is on ctan. You will have to install it manually.

Comment: Maybe you can try the `matlab-prettifier` package instead, that can be installed in MikTeX and it also has dedicated Matlab syntax highlighting. `mcode` itself can be downloaded from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package and installed manually.